# How do i populate a dropdown list by selecting the value from another dropdown list?

Tags: php, mysql, data-binding, drop-down-menu, dynamic-data

I have been trying to populate the contents of one drop down list with the selection of an item in another, using php,html and mysql database and Its proved to be a lot harder than i thought for me. I'm trying to get one dropdown list show names of all mobile phones based on company selections in the first drop down list.

The code i've provided below has no errors, but the 2nd dropdown list is not getting populated. the variable '$submittedValue' is not getting the right value and hence '$name' also has no content in it. I can't seem to be able to figure out a reason for this.

what i've done is, to try to use the selected option in the first drop down list, put that into a variable and pass that as a parameter to the 2nd query.

I solution to this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbmobiles");

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $options = '';
 $submittedValue = '';
 $name=" ";

 $q1=mysqli_query($con,"select distinct compName from umobile order by compName ASC");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q1)) {
    $options .="<option value=". $row['compName'] ." >" . $row['compName'] .    "</option>";
 }

 $menu1 = "<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action=' '>    
           <p><label>Select Company</label></p>
           <select name='filter' id='filter'>
           " . $options . "
           </select>
          </form>";

 if (isset($_POST["filter"])) {
    $submittedValue = $_POST["filter"];
 }
 echo $menu1;

 if ($q2=mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT DISTINCT mobname FROM umobile WHERE compName=? "))
 {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q2,"s",$submittedValue);
    $s=$submittedValue;
    mysqli_stmt_execute($q2);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($q2,$r);
 }  

 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($q2)) {
    $name .="<option>".$r['mobname']."</option>";
 }

 echo ".$name.";
 $menu2 = "<form id='moblist' name='moblist' method='post' action=' '>
            <p><label>Select Mobile</label></p>
            <select name='moblist' id='moblist'>
            " . $name . "
            </select>
           </form>";

 echo $menu2;
?>
```

Comment: what is values of $options .="<option value=". $row['compName'] ." >" . $row['compName'] .    "</option>";


try print_r($row)

Comment: that is to build the 1st drop down list , containing names of all mobile companies. That bit is working fine, the problem begins after that

Comment: @AmanMehrotra Got it : Look at my updated answer at the bottom.

Comment: GOT IT! thanks a lot ! :D 1 small little optimization for some specific results though... for companies with 2 words in their name. isn't recognizing it. for some reason the POST is taking only the 1st word. apart from that worked! thank you for your help. :)

Comment: look at my next update.

Comment: you have effectively made my day, sir. highly helpful and patient you've been, thanks! Working perfectly now. :D

Comment: Now that's OK . Please remove your table design from your question. It's not important anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to quote `.$r['mobname'].`

```
$name .="<option value=\"".$r['mobname']."\" >".$r['mobname']."</option>";
```

Your $_POST tests only .

```
if (isset($_POST["filter"])) {
    $submittedValue = $_POST["filter"];
}
```

What about if $_POST["filter"] is **NOT set** ?
Your code did not take care of this fact. He always runs through the section $menu2.

Your $_POST is as the name implies, of a post. To evaluate a $_POST must be done a post.

```
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

for example

```
 $menu1 = "<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action=' '>    
             <p><label>Select Company</label></p>
            <select name='filter' id='filter'>
             " . $options . "
            </select>
            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"Send\" />
          </form>";
```

Put all the logic for the second menu in your code `if (isset($_POST["filter"])) {`

```
 echo $menu1;

 if (isset($_POST["filter"])) {
    $submittedValue = $_POST["filter"];
      if ($q2= ....)
       {
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q2,"s",$submittedValue);
         $s=$submittedValue;
         mysqli_stmt_execute($q2);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($q2,$r);

         while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($q2)) {
         $name .="<option value=\"".$r['mobname']."\" >".$r['mobname']."</option>";
         }

         $menu2 = "<form id='moblist' name='moblist' method='post' action=' '>
            <p><label>Select Mobile</label></p>
            <select name='moblist' id='moblist'>
            " . $name . "
            </select>
           </form>";

        echo $menu2;
       }  
   }
```

**Update:**

You can not use $r['mobname'] with a bind.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($q2,$r);
....
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($q2)) {
$name .="<option value=\"".$r['mobname']."\" >".$r['mobname']."</option>";
```

}

Use it like .

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($q2,$r);
....
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($q2)) {
$name .="<option value=\"".$r."\" >".$r."</option>";
}


mysqli_stmt_close($q2);
```

**Update 2**

you forget to quote that to

```
 $options .="<option value=". $row['compName'] ." >" . $row['compName'] .    "</option>";
```

right

```
 $options .="<option value=\"". $row['compName'] ."\" >" . $row['compName'] .    "</option>";
```

Comment: you are right about that, thank you. i have edited that, but however have struck a new error :/  the string $name is still not getting the correct values( only first alphabets)thanks.but it has given way for the next new error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'mobname' in C:\xampp\htdocs\source\page.php on line 47"

Comment: I made the changes you specified. the error remained the same. It seems to be picking only the first alphabet for the every phone and then moving onto the next option. what that tells me is that maybe there is is some sort of variable mistake i've made. still says "Warning: Illegal string offset 'mobname"

Comment: @AmanMehrotra : Look at my updated answer at the top for the right syntax for $name;

Comment: still the same. i think its happening maybe cause the value i'm taking i'm taking is a character variable and not as a string ?

Comment: But your ERROR is gone : "Warning: Illegal string offset 'mobname' "

Comment: nope, its still there. Is there any other way to tackle this paticular task ?

Comment: Show us your Table `umobile` design.

Comment: have added a page of the table at the end of the codebox in the question.

Comment: have added the design of the table as well to end of the code block. apologies, didn't read that before.

Comment: @AmanMehrotra : Got it : Look at my updated answer at the bottom

Comment: GOT IT! thanks a lot ! :D 1 small little optimization for some specific results though... for companies with 2 words in their name. isn't recognizing it. for some reason the POST is taking only the 1st word. apart from that worked! thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$menu1 = "<form id='filter' name='filter_form' method='post' action=' '>    
           <p><label>Select Company</label></p>
           <select onchange='filter_form.submit()' name='filter' id='filter'>
           " . $options . "
           </select>
          </form>";
```

there is no submit button in your form , either place a submit button or try to submit on selection on dropdown values.
Only then if($_POST['filter']) will be true and your variable will successfully get assignment

Comment: thank you for your input, but adding a submit button would defeat the purpose and feel. i could go for that. if it is possible, could you please elaborate on how i can submit on selection, automatically ?

Comment: code edited, avoid using same name for too many tags and varaible(filter used so many times)

Comment: Follow like Aman:

<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action=' '>
<select name="formGender" onChange="filter.submit()">
  <option value="">Gender Please..</option>
  <option value="M">Male</option>
  <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' />
</form>

Comment: you are using same variable name for form and selection box, change them and you will get it working.refer above code pasted.

Comment: hi, that did forward the execution of the query a great deal, the box is populating, however the string $name is still not getting the correct values( only first alphabets)thanks.but it has given way for the next new error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'mobname' in C:\xampp\htdocs\source\page.php on line 47"

Comment: print_r($_POST), verify you are actually getting data after  post, then try to print query, may be that one is not forming well.

Comment: yes, i am getting the data, but like i said, only the first alphabet of every mobile phone. why do you think that is happening ?

Comment: actually your first dropdown is not gaining selected property